# Передача двух значений в функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу по клике на ссылку передать два значения в функцию, делаю так:

```
onclick="gov('.$id.', "info")
```

при клике получаю ошибку в консоле хрома: `Uncaught ReferenceError: info is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

Функция: `function gov(id, type) { ... }`

при передачи одного значения все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD. Заметил что если вторым значением передавать цифру - все работает, а с текстом нет

Comment: Перестаньте использовать `on...` атрибуты. Очень рекомендую

Comment: похоже на очепятку, попробуйте обернуть `'info'` в одинарные кавычки

Comment: @yolosora в одинарные нельзя, потому что это ссылка в `echo '<a ...>';`

Comment: @Денис экранируйте их

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от того, чем является `info`. Если просто строкой, значит надо писать либо так

```
onclick="gov('.$id.', 'info')"
```

либо экранировать двойные кавычки

```
onclick="gov('.$id.', \"info\")"
```

> в одинарные нельзя, потому что это ссылка в `echo '<a ...>'`;

Значит надо работать с экранированием внутри вывода строки в  PHP:

```
<?php
$id = 10;
echo '<a href="#" onclick="gov('.$id.', \'infoHello\')">click me</a>'

?>

<script>
function gov(id, type) {
    alert(id + ', ' + type);
}
</script>
```

Comment: info просто строка, слово. не помогло((

Comment: не верю https://jsfiddle.net/vupf3zuk/

Comment: @Денис взглянул на комментарий под вопросом. Добавил в ответ. В общем всё сводится к экранированию. Если не в JS, то в PHP. Надо это помнить всегда, если уж рисуете много кавычек в строке

Answer (score 0):

Так *не надо делать*

```
echo '<a href="" onclick="gov('.$id.', \'info\')">';
```

Поскольку у вас есть jQuery, можно сделать, например, так:

```
$params = htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'type' => 'info')));
echo '<a href="" data-params="' . $params . '">';
```

Дальше в `<script>`

```
$('[data-params]').on('click', function(e) {
    var params = $(this).data('params');
    gov(params.id, params.type);
}
```